# Is this possible to migrate user records from one organization to another using SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx, migration, data-migration

I am trying to migrate users from one org to another using SFDX.
If I include `ProfileId` and `UserRoleId`, I receive errors
Reference UserRole not found for UserRoleId.  Skipping record undefined
and

```
$ sfdx force:data:tree:export -q  "Select Username, FirstName, LastName, Email, Alias, Title, Department, UserRoleId, TimeZoneSidKey, LocaleSidKey, EmailEncodingKey, ProfileId, LanguageLocaleKey from user where CommunityNickname IN ('fsuzuki','ahartzler')" -u rr2 --outputdir data --plan
ERROR:  Reference UserRole not found for UserRoleId.  Skipping record undefined.
ERROR:  Reference Profile not found for ProfileId.  Skipping record undefined.
ERROR:  Reference UserRole not found for UserRoleId.  Skipping record undefined.
ERROR:  Reference Profile not found for ProfileId.  Skipping record undefined.
Wrote 2 records to data\Users.json
Wrote 0 records to data\User-plan.json
```

When I try to import, I receive an error that required fields are missing.

```
$ sfdx force:data:tree:import -u rr --plan data/User-plan.json
ERROR running force:data:tree:import:  {"hasErrors":true,"results":[{"referenceId":"UserRef1","errors":[{"statusCode":"REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING","message":"Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]","fields":["ProfileId"]}]},{"referenceId":"UserRef2","errors":[{"statusCode":"REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING","message":"Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]","fields":["ProfileId"]}]}]}
```

If I include Profile name and UserRole name in export, export doesn't bring any errors

```
$ sfdx force:data:tree:export -q  "Select Username, FirstName, LastName, Email, Alias, Title, Department, UserRole.Id, TimeZoneSidKey, LocaleSidKey, EmailEncodingKey, Profile.Id, LanguageLocaleKey, Profile.Name, UserRole.DeveloperName, UserRole.Name from user where CommunityNickname IN ('fsuzuki','ahartzler')" -u rr2 --outputdir data --plan
Wrote 2 records to data\Users.json
Wrote 0 records to data\User-plan.json
```

but then receive the errors `Cannot reference a foreign key field UserRole` and `Cannot reference a foreign key field Profile.`

```
$ sfdx force:data:tree:import -u rr --plan data/User-plan.json
ERROR running force:data:tree:import:  {"hasErrors":true,"results":
[{"reference Id":"UserRef1","errors":[{"statusCode":"INVALID_FIELD","message":"Cannot refere
nce a foreign key field Profile.","fields":[]},{"statusCode":"INVALID_FIELD","m
essage":"Cannot reference a foreign key field UserRole.","fields":[]}]},{"refer
enceId":"UserRef2","errors":[{"statusCode":"INVALID_FIELD","message":"Cannot re
ference a foreign key field Profile.","fields":[]},{"statusCode":"INVALID_FIELD
","message":"Cannot reference a foreign key field UserRole.","fields":[]}]}]}
```

Comment: I think the original export SOQL query needs to do a subquery for each child relationship as well, so that those records are available when trying to do the import.  See the [Parent to Child Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html) example

Comment: in this case, Profile and UserRole are not child relationships, but they are parent relationships

Comment: So Parent to child query example is not applicable here

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is not possible to achieve without apex.
However, apex code can be called from sfdx.

So, we can write some file `createUsers.apex` and place it in `scripts/apex` folder of `sfdx` project.

```
String aron = 'Username=julfy@ah.rr,FirstName=Aaron,LastName=Hartzler,Email=julfy@i.ua,Alias=ahart,Title=Customer Support Rep,Department=Customer Support,TimeZoneSidKey=Europe/Dublin,LocaleSidKey=en_IE_EURO,EmailEncodingKey=ISO-8859-1,LanguageLocaleKey=en_US';
String fu = 'Username=julfy@fs.rr,FirstName=Fumiko,LastName=Suzuki,Email=julfy@i.ua,Alias=fsuzu,Title=Customer Support Rep,Department=Customer Support,TimeZoneSidKey=Asia/Tokyo,LocaleSidKey=ja_JP,EmailEncodingKey=ISO-8859-1,LanguageLocaleKey=ja';
Map<String, SObject> groupByName(List<SObject> records) {
    Map<String, SObject> m = new Map<String, SObject>();
    for (SObject r: records) {
        m.put(String.valueOf(r.get('Name')), r);
    }
    return m;
}
User createUser(String data, String role, String profile) {
    List<String> items = data.split(',');
    User u = new User();
    for (String item: items) {
        List<String> keyValue = item.split('=');
        u.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    }
    u.ProfileId = profileMap.get(profile).Id;
    u.UserRoleId = roleMap.get(role).Id;
    u.IsActive = false;
    return u;
}
Map<String, SObject> profileMap = groupByName([SELECT Name FROM Profile]);
Map<String, SObject> roleMap = groupByName([SELECT Name FROM UserRole]);

insert new List<User>{
    createUser(aron, 'Customer Support, North America', 'Standard User'),
    createUser(fu, 'Customer Support, International', 'Standard Platform User')
};
```

and finally from command line the following command can be executed

```
sfdx force:apex:execute -f scripts/apex/createUsers.apex -u rr
```

The code can be adapted to use CSV or JSON or key-values pair format

Answer (score 0):

I liked Patlatus answer above but it expects each user to be a separate variable constructed with all the required attributes. Instead make use of the sObject tree as is you get while exporting and read in the  anonymous apex you write.
I tried something like below

```
String usersJson = '{records:[the records array from sObject tree export goes here]}';

Map<String, Object> usersJsonObj = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(usersJson);
Object obj = usersJsonObj.get('records');
List<Object> objList = (List<Object>)usersJsonObj.get('records');
List<User> usersList = new List<User>();
Profile sysAdminProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
for(Object userObj : objList) {
    System.debug(userObj);
    Map<String,Object> userFields = (Map<String,Object>)userObj;
    usersList.add(new User(Alias=userFields.get('Alias').toString(),
                Username=userFields.get('Username').toString(),
                Email=userFields.get('Email').toString(),
                FirstName=userFields.get('FirstName').toString(),
                LastName=userFields.get('LastName').toString(),
                LocaleSidKey=userFields.get('LocaleSidKey').toString(),
                LanguageLocaleKey=userFields.get('LanguageLocaleKey').toString(),
                EmailEncodingKey=userFields.get('EmailEncodingKey').toString(),
                TimeZoneSidKey=userFields.get('TimeZoneSidKey').toString(),
                ProfileId=sysAdminProfile.Id));
}
if(usersList.size() > 0) {
    try {
        insert usersList;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('Exception message ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: My version gives the flexibility to use different profile assignment and role assignment